# Problem with YouTube videos and audio

Tags: sound, google-chrome, video, youtube, video-streaming

I recently switched from Windows to Linux. I am using Google Chrome Browser. When I play video on YouTube there is a glitch in the video like broken texture and also a problem with the audio of the video.

I downloaded the same video and played it in VLC which works perfectly.

My internet connection is pretty good.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core  
Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series 
Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your pc is rather old for hd video , but try Firefox which now uses graphic acceleration if hardware is compatible (not Chrome AFAIK)